# HAProxy blocks only first request

Tags: haproxy

I have the following `frontend` configuration for HAProxy:

```
frontend www_front
    bind *:80
    bind *:8080
    mode http
    option httplog
    default_backend www_back
    acl restrict_page path_sub /manager
    acl restrict_page url_sub  /manager
    http-request deny if restrict_page
```

After restarting the `haproxy` service, the first access to `http://x.x.x.x/manager` indeed returned `403 Forbidden`. However, subsequent accesses to the same URL did not get blocked.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so apparently **there were multiple haproxy processes running simultaneously**.

So, if you end up here because you are in the same situation, here's the solution:

First, stop `haproxy` using the init script.

Next, check that there are NO other `haproxy` processes running; use `pkill haproxy`, and if that fails, `pkill -9 haproxy`.

Finally, restart `haproxy`.